# Angular Model value is not updated when select value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have following code in my controller

```
$scope.currencies = [
    { "currency_code": "USD", "currency_name": "American Dollar" },
    { "currency_code": "AUD", "currency_name": "Australian Dollar" }, 
    { "currency_code": "BRL", "currency_name": "Brazilian Real" }, 
    { "currency_code": "CAD", "currency_name": "Canadian Dollar" }, 
    { "currency_code": "CHF", "currency_name": "Swiss Franc" }, 
    { "currency_code": "CLP", "currency_name": "Chilean Peso" }
]

$scope.selectedCurrency = "USD";

$scope.doStuffs = function(){
   alert($scope.selectedCurrency);
}
```

And in my View

```
<div class="selected_currency">{{selectedCurrency}}</div>
<select id="currency" name="currency" ng-model="selectedCurrency" 
ng-options="currency.currency_code as currency.currency_code for currency in currencies"> 
</select>
```

**Problem**

When I change the currency from select, and execute the `doStuffs()` function, it alerts default value `USD`, the model `selectedCurrency` is not taking the changed value.

However expression `{{selectedCurrency}}` works pretty well.

Can anyone tell me how to update model when select value changes?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

*This didn't work*

```
<ion-view view-title="My Stuffs" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ion-content> 
           <!-- other tags -->
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

However, following code worked (I just defined `ng-controller` directive in `ion-content` tag)

```
<ion-view view-title="My Stuffs">
        <ion-content  ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
               <!-- other tags -->
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: When are you executing `$scope.doStuffs`?

Comment: When do you invoke `doStuffs` ? Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/L3grpLo9/

Comment: `doStuffs()` is invoked on button click

Comment: @Rayon, seems working fine in Jsfiddle, but not in my case, strange!

Comment: @WatsMyName, I am quiet sure this must be a silly mistake.. Do share a Fiddle so that one can have a look..

Comment: @Rayon please check my update in original post, now it works but I wonder why it didn't work previously

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ng-change="doStuffs()"` in select element

```
<select 
   id="currency" 
   name="currency" 
   ng-model="selectedCurrency" 
   ng-change="doStuffs()"
   ng-options="currency.currency_code as currency.currency_code 
   for currency in currencies"> 
</select>
```

Please demo here
https://plnkr.co/edit/1gueFbhKkRrqmRiSoTYB?p=preview

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this answer, but it doesn't alert correct value even on change event

Comment: @WarsMyName please check this link https://plnkr.co/edit/1gueFbhKkRrqmRiSoTYB?p=preview

Comment: This is not my solution, my code isn't working as it should.. This is same as what I did. However i solved it, see my update in original question

Comment: can you explain what is your problem.?

Answer (score 0):

To get updated or change value inside your controller, you need to write ng-change function on it

```
<select id="currency" name="currency" ng-model="selectedCurrency" ng-change="doStuffs()" ng-options="currency.currency_code as currency.currency_code 
   for currency in currencies">
</select>
```

Code

```
$scope.doStuffs = function(){
console.log($scope.selectedCurrency);}
```

Answer (score 0):

2-way binding works in angular when values are updated by reference. In your example the model `selectedCurrency` is a primitive `string` in javascript and will never be update via refernce and the value change won't work in 2-way.

In order to make it work, bind the model to an attribute of object:

**Controller**

```
$scope.model.selectedCurrency = 'USD';
```

**HTML**

```
ng-model="model.selectedCurrency"
```